# ajax contact form doesn't send POST data to php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I made an html form width ajax:

```
    function confirmSendMail() {

    $(".send_contact").click(function(event){

        event.preventDefault(); 

        var nome = $("#inputName").val();
        var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
        var telefono = $("#inputTelefono").val();
        var messaggio = $("#message").val();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "send.php",

            data: "nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&telefono=" + telefono + "&messaggio=" + messaggio,

            success: function(msg) {
                alert('messaggio inviato!')
            },

            error: function() {
                alert("Si e' verificato un errore imprevisto...");
            }

        }); 

    return false;     

    });

}
```

the alert confirm me that the mail is sent, and the php engine send the email... but it is empty, as the POST doesn't send data to php:

```
    <?php
require 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$nome = $_POST['inputName'];
$email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$telefono = $_POST['inputTelefono'];
$messaggio = $_POST['message'];

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $email;
$mail->AddAddress('mimelaine.dhampiro@gmail.com');              // Add a recipient

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
/* $mail->AddAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->AddAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name */
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'email dal form acfmavvocati.it';
$mail->Body    = 'nome: ' . $nome . '<br /><br />email: ' . $email . '<br /><br />telefono: ' . $telefono . '<br /><br />messaggio: ' . $messaggio;
/* $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients'; */

if($mail->Send()) {
    echo "works";
    exit;
} else {

    echo "doesn't work";
    exit;

}

?>
```

I tried many solutions, it brings me mad.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes in your PHP file.

It should be

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$messaggio = $_POST['messaggio'];
```

as you already declared the names in the AJAX data

```
data: "nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&telefono=" + telefono + "&messaggio=" + messaggio,
```

Comment: you're right! As I usually use the "action" in forms, I'm not so expert in ajax post data. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You check wrong $_POST keys which are not set in your ajax data string:

```
$nome = $_POST['inputName'];
$email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
$telefono = $_POST['inputTelefono'];
$messaggio = $_POST['message'];
```

change them to:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$messaggio = $_POST['messagio'];
```